# Custom change-id in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

Is it possible to have a 'custom' change-id in a gerrit commit message?

For example,

```
- My commit message

Change-Id: BM10945
```

Where `BM10945` is the bluemine ticket the change is for.

I keep getting a `(missing or invalid Change-Id line format in commit message footer)` from gerrit, and can't commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't.  You need to use Gerrit's own Change-Id format.  You can have one autogenerated for your commit by installing the *commit-msg* hook script included with Gerrit.  More information is available at the [Gerrit Change-Ids documentation](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.0/user-changeid.html).

Comment: @SummerBreeze It needs to start with the capital `I`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [commentlink](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/config-gerrit.html#_a_id_commentlink_a_section_commentlink) config to automatically parse ticket numbers in commit messages, and show them as links in the Gerrit web interface.

E.g. for your redmine ones:

```
[commentlink "redmine"]
  match = "(BM[0-9]+)"
  html = "<a href='http://www.redmine.org/issues/$1'>$1</a>"
```

Also, you can use the [TrackingID to add a footer containing a link to a tracking database](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/config-gerrit.html#_a_id_trackingid_a_section_trackingid) although note that if you're using the simplest setup which uses the embedded H2 database, the you have to run the [ScanTrackingIds](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/pgm-ScanTrackingIds.html) program manually when Gerrit is offline which doesn't make it feasible.

Finally, if you want some other form of linking tickets to redmine tickets, such as email updates containing a link or make gerrit actions (publish patchset, merge) update the ticket, use [Gerrit hooks](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/config-gerrit.html#_a_id_hooks_a_section_hooks) (slightly different than regular git hooks) and [some scripting](https://github.com/tru/redmine-gerrit-scripts) to connect them.

Comment: Ooo that's awesome!  We might end up doing that, thanks @Motti!

Answer (score 2):

In complement to [Carl Norum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17929703/612206), you can indeed create your own ChangeId as long as :

- It starts with an uppercase I;
- It contains 32 hexadecimal characters;

One sample format could be :

```
I201611160832aa0000000000786176696572
```

It starts with the date and time (`YYYYMMDDHHMM`), followed by a separator, and then the name of the committer in hexa format (here i used ascii, but one could use another format), padded with 00.

Comment: By my reading of the documentation, "... Change-Ids are *typically* prefixed with an uppercase I." the format is not specified. Ref: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html#_description